# G Suite - I want to send emails using two domain names using one email account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, dmarc

Assume, that I have two domains:

1. a.com (in this domain I create account)
2. b.pl (additional domain)

I want to give the user x the ability to send emails as x@a.com and x@b.pl via one email account.

Is such a scenario possible in GSuite?

The most similar functionality I managed to find is "Add alias" in admin panel, while adding alias in Gmail via "Settings". -> "Accounts" -> "Send as".

The problem is that this configuration causes a behavior similar to that of logging into a.com account by the telnet and then spoofing the "from" header as b.pl.

```
Delivered-To: y@b.pl
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@a-com.20150623.gappssmtp.com header.s=20150623 header.b=E51gIexv;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of x@a.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=x@a.com
Return-Path: <x@a.com>
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of x@a.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.220.41;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@a-com.20150623.gappssmtp.com header.s=20150623 header.b=E51gIexv;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of x@a.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=x@a.com
From: "X" <x@b.pl>
Subject: Test message
To: Y <y@b.pl>
```

This configuration fails DMARC so I want to improve it.

```
dmarc=fail (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=QUARANTINE) header.from=b.pl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To fix this:**
You may want to setup DKIM signing for both domains. Follow [this guidance.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174126?hl=en)

Google should sign the emails with the private key that corresponds to the public key for the domain that is in the `Header.From` field.

**What happened:**
For `DMARC` to pass, either DKIM or SPF should produce a Pass, in alignment with the organizational domain in the `Header.From`, in your case `b.pl`

Google is DKIM signing your emails using its own key pair for domain `a-com.20150623.gappssmtp.com`. That doesn't align with your organizational domain `b.pl` and thus doesn't Pass `DMARC`.

On the other hand, the `Header.From` field contains an address in the domain `b.pl`, while the `Return-Path` is set to an address in the domain `a.com`. So for SPF to produce a `DMARC` Pass, the required alignment is missing as well.